# Get default cornerRadius

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way in Swift / SwiftUI to get the default `cornerRadius` the app uses for Views?

I'm aware I can use the `.cornerRaidus` modifier to set a custom radius, what I want is the default iOS is using on that version.

Comment: Which views do you mean?

Comment: Specifically `Form` or `List` with the `InsetGroupedListStyle()`

Comment: I do not think there is something like that as public api, may you start making a matching cornerRadius for all apple devices and keep it up to date.

Comment: I believe it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to match the radius of the container, Apple provides `ContainerRelativeShape()` for that purpose. You apply it in a background like this:

```
Text("Hello World!")
    .background(ContainerRelativeShape()
        .fill(Color.blue)
    )
```